# No touch controls responding in Expo Go on iOS, even with default template code

Tags: ios, expo

I'm very new to javascript as a whole, let alone React-Native and expo. As I've been learning about it more, I've started to mess around with making projects. However, I'm noticing that when I start the environment, and load the Expo Go app on my phone, I can't input anything on my device. This includes tabs and links, but also the three touch and shake gestures of Expo Go itself. Is this an issue someone has experienced before? I"ve done some searches but can't seem to find much.

I've tried multiple installations of Expo Go, and reinstalling Node and all the various other packages on my own, all to no avail. This persisted with expo, expo-router, and basic react-native. I was expecting the links to work given the use of expo router templates, though the lack of Expo Go app controls leads me to believe this is an issue of iOS.